# Excel help: Finding average of 3 data sets with different number of data points. The data sets have been normalised to 100

Tags: excel, mean

I have 3 sets of [data](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgZ61v_RxqL_2nqh9CmjV0R2-RYy), each normalised to 100, but with a different number of data points. The end goal is to get the average of the 3 graphs. Pic below. Thanks in advance...any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy might be a concern in this solution. You need to get Y-values from each curve for the same X and average them. 
lets work with one table from your data.

in any column(Here `J`) create a list of X-values from 2 to 100. In another column use this formula

```
M2 =MATCH(J2,$A$2:$A$127,1)
```

Where `J2` is the X-value, `A2:A127` are the x-values from the data table

in the next 2 columns enter

```
N2 =INDEX(LINEST(OFFSET($A$1,M2,1,3,1),OFFSET($A$1,M2,0,3,1)),1)
O2 =INDEX(LINEST(OFFSET($A$1,M2,1,3,1),OFFSET($A$1,M2,0,3,1)),2)
```

`A1` is just a reference after which the data table starts. `N2` and `O2` give the slope and intercept of a straight line that is fitted around our chosen x value.

`P2 =N2*J2+O2` gives you the approximate y value for the chosen x value from the data table.

create similar tables for other two data tables. Now you can just average the y values.

Here is a [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_UHj6QJgmFknwefsIooqAZNR0CHdJU7zXE0Fa7S56w0/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: sheet has been deleted :|